# Replacement for Bootstrap-Tokenfield

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

So it seems like `bootstrap-tokenfield` is no longer supported (https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/issues/255) which is a bummer because it's so easy to use. Anyone know a good alternative?

Comment: I am brand new with JavaScript and HTML, but I am trying to learn how to use [KaneCohen/tokenfield][1]. As of eight days ago, they were still fixing problems related to the project. They don't have many examples or a lot for beginners. I am trying to pull data from a server and they only have a partial example.


  [1]: https://github.com/KaneCohen/tokenfield "KaneCohen/tokenfield"